Differentiation of Surface Integral with Parameter-Dependent Surface
I am dealing with the differentiation of a surface integral where the surface depends on a parameter. Specifically, I am interested in the expression:
$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{g(\Omega,\theta)}\varphi(y)d\sigma$,
where $\Omega=[0,1]\times[0,1]\subset R^2$, $\Theta\subset R$ is an open interval; $g:\Omega \times \Theta \mapsto R^3$ and $\varphi:R^3\mapsto R$ are smooth functions, and $\sigma$ is the area element.
To build intuition, I chose a simple example where $g(\omega,\theta)= A\omega+ b(\theta)$ is an affine function with
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0\\ 0 &1 \\ 1 &1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $b(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}-\theta\\ \frac{1}{2}-\theta \\ \frac{1}{4}-\theta \end{bmatrix}$.
I applied the Leibniz rule as introduced in Section 5 of Flanders' paper Differentiation Under the Integral Sign, specifically eq. (5.1), to the following integral:
$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{g(\Omega,\theta)}\varphi(y)\overrightarrow n \cdot d\overrightarrow\sigma$,
where $\overrightarrow n$ is the normal vector of the surface $g(\Omega,\theta)$. In this example, $g(\Omega,\theta)$ is a hyperplane in $R^3$ and its normal vector is constant. After performing some calculations, I arrived at:
$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{g(\Omega,\theta)}\varphi(y)\overrightarrow n \cdot d\overrightarrow\sigma = \sqrt{3}\int_{g(\Omega,\theta)} \text{div} (\varphi(y)\overrightarrow n) d\sigma$.
At this point, I'm stuck. Since the result takes the form of a divergence integral, I wonder if there's a version of the divergence theorem that could transform this surface integral into a line integral along the boundary of the surface $g(\partial \Omega, \theta)$. Any insights on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated.
